# Comparative data on agricultural subsidies

Tags: data-request, agriculture

Where can I find data on the agricultural subsidies of each country, ideally in a comparable fashion? I've googled without success. I hope there are some experts on this forum that can direct me to specialized data sources, or perhaps books.

It seems this is all surrounded with secrecy, so no much is available online.

World bank website doesn't have this information.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area... but my guess is that the World Bank should have this data.

Comment: Thank you Art. There is nothing here: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the OECD. An annual report is produced. Latest is here:

https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/agriculture-and-food/agricultural-policy-monitoring-and-evaluation-2019_39bfe6f3-en

Answer (score 1):

Which countries are you looking at? [This paper](http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/734701543906677048/pdf/132660-REPLACEMENT-PUBLIC-Realigning-Agricultural-Support-CSA-v2.pdf) seems to suggest there's data from OECD countries.

You might also take a look [here](https://www.worldbank.org/en/research/brief/distortions-to-agricultural-incentives) and [here](https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/estimates-distortions-agricultural-incentives-1955-2007-report-no-wps4612-412008-wps4864-3). I downloaded zip files and, if I understand correctly, there seem to be data of subsidies by country, product, and year.